# Tooltip flickering while typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I have tooltip which would warn when the user is entering a number which is not in the allowed range.

Everything works fine, but the only problem is the flickering of the tooltip, as I type it flickers and if I hold down a number for long, I won't even see the tooltip.

So anyway to solve around this?

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nxojbjzp/)**

```
<div class="row">
<label for="labelinput">Win Chance</label>
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="chance" value="50">
</div>
```

JS

```
$( document ).ready() block.
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
       $('#chance').tooltip('dispose');
    });

$('#chance').attr({"data-toggle": "tooltip", "title": "WinChance must be between 10 - 90"});
  $('#chance').on('input', function() {
     if(parseFloat(this.value) > 90.00 ){        
        $('#chance').tooltip('show')
      }  else if(parseFloat(this.value) < 10.00 ) {
         $('#chance').tooltip('show')
      }
         else {
         $('#chance').tooltip('dispose');
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhatnagar018/nxojbjzp/18/).

I think you are looking for this behavior.

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
      $('#chance').tooltip('dispose');
    });

    $('#chance').attr({
      "data-toggle": "tooltip",
      "title": "WinChance must be between 10 - 90"
    });
    $('#chance').on('input', function() {
      console.log(parseFloat(this.value));
      if (parseFloat(this.value) > 90.00 && $('div.tooltip').length === 0) {
        $('#chance').tooltip('show')
      } else if (parseFloat(this.value) < 10.00 && $('div.tooltip').length === 0) {
        $('#chance').tooltip('show')
      }
      //It's an optional condition if you want than only add else remove it.
      else if ($('div.tooltip').length && parseFloat(this.value) > 10.00 && parseFloat(this.value) < 90.00) {
        $('#chance').tooltip('dispose');
      }

    });
```

Comment: Exactly what I want.

Answer (score -1):

Add blur
 $('#chance').on('blur', function() {.....

Comment: No I don't want blur, as I  want the tooltip to show instantly not when it is lost focus.